# Element border rotation

Tags: javascript, css

I have 2 elements like that:

```
<div class="element"><span></span></div>
```

Element must have a border rounded(CSS) and on hover the border must be dashed(CSS) and rotate, but span shoulde be static. Any help?

```css
@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
.element {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #ededed;
  color: @fff;

}
.element:hover {
  animation: rotate 2s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: rotate 2s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: rotate 2s infinite linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="element"><span>1</span>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by rotate? Do you mean the dashes in the border should move around the element?

Comment: the dashes in the border should move around the element, yes.

Comment: this is test code. How can i get, that span don't move with div?

Comment: Or how can i rotate border, for ex, if i have 1 span, maybe javascript helps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.element {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border:3px solid grey;
  border-radius:50%;
  margin: 25px auto;
  line-height: 250px;
  text-align: center;
 }

.element:hover {
  border-style:dashed;
  animation: spin 10s infinite linear;
}

.element:hover span {
  animation: spin 10s infinite reverse linear;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% { transform: rotate(1turn); }
}
```

```html
<div class="element"><span>Not Spinning On Hover</span></div>
```

Comment: @Александр I think this one will not work if the content (Not spinning..) is not in the middle, I removed the `line-height` from element and here you can see the result - http://jsfiddle.net/3ptqvrze/

Comment: Well you'll have to provide your actual code but the principle is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I believe ***[this](http://codepen.io/techniq/pen/gzyHI)*** codepen has the result you need. However, this approach needs additional `<span>` elements inside the `<div>`.

Comment: this is interesting, but i need another. Look up, spin and revers spin, that's exactly what i need.